# How to add a collection of list into a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my code like,

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
model.QuestionSetList = new  List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < response.QuestionsInfoList.Count(); i++)
{
     list.Add(response.QuestionSetInfo.QuestionsInfoList[i].Question);
     foreach (AnswerSetContract answerSetContract in response.QuestionsInfoList[i].AnswersInfoList)
     {
         list.Add(answerSetContract.AnswerText);
     }
     model.QuestionSetList.Add(list)
}
```

I cannot add a list into another list.Kindly tell me what to do in this case.

Comment: What's/Where's the error you are getting in this code?

Comment: Under model.QuestionSetList.Add(list). throwing an error "The best overloaded method match for 'system.collections.generic.list<string>' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: The error is here: `model.QuestionSetList.Add(list)`. You can replace `Add` with `AddRange` (it will flatten added list) or change type of `QuestionSetList` to list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `Concat` function within the `System.Linq` namespace

I.e.

```
using System.Linq;

List<string> list = new List<string>();
model.QuestionSetList = new  List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < response.QuestionsInfoList.Count(); i++)
{
     list.Add(response.QuestionSetInfo.QuestionsInfoList[i].Question);
     foreach (AnswerSetContract answerSetContract in response.QuestionsInfoList[i].AnswersInfoList)
     {
         list.Add(answerSetContract.AnswerText);
     }
     model.QuestionSetList = model.QuestionSetList.Concat(list);
}
```

But why not at the place of; `list.Add(answerSetContract.AnswerText);` add it directly to `model.QuestionSetList`?

So like this;

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
model.QuestionSetList = new  List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < response.QuestionsInfoList.Count(); i++)
{
     list.Add(response.QuestionSetInfo.QuestionsInfoList[i].Question);
     foreach (AnswerSetContract answerSetContract in response.QuestionsInfoList[i].AnswersInfoList)
     {
         model.QuestionSetList.Add(answerSetContract.AnswerText);
     }
}
```

Comment: Good! Please accept this as an answer if it helped! :)

Comment: Could you please tell me, what is the difference between,  model.QuestionSetList.AddRange(list); and model.QuestionSetList.Concat(list);

Comment: The main difference is that `AddRange` adds the items from `list` to (the original list) `model.QuestionSetList` while `Concat` creates a new list with the values from both lists.

Comment: A list, in this form, has nothing to do with it's visual representation. Depending on what you would want to achieve you will have to think of a solution for that in your UI.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `List` of `List`s, then your `QuestionSetList` would have to be:

```
model.QuestionSetList = new List<List<<string>>()
```

Consider creating a custom type though, otherwise it's a bit like inception, list in a list in a list in a list.........

Or if you're actually wanting to **combine** the `Lists`, then use `Concat`:

```
list1.Concat(list2);
```

Comment: remember that `Concat` returns a new list, so your example (in its current form) wouldn't do much.. a better example might be `list1 = list1.Concat(list2)`, however, that would be the same as `AddRange` only (IMO) obfuscated. If the OP wanted a *new* list however `Concat` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with AddRange, it allows to add a collection to a List

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx

Comment: instead of just posting a link, could you perhaps add an example of how to use it? that way, those you wonder how it is used can read it here instead of having to visit a new page.

Answer (score 0):

model.QuestionSetList is a list of strings.
You're trying to add a list of strings to it. As their types are incompatible, it won't allow you to do that.

Try making model.QuestionSetList a `List<List<string>>` and see if that helps you.